# Bootstrap Form Helper State Picker Based on Country

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-form-helper

I have the bootstrap Country picker working (using a div tag instead of the select tag provided on their website). However, I can't get the state picker to show state options based on country selected.

Here are the files I have linked:

```
<!-- Bootstrap Form Helpers -->
<link href="http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/assets/css/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Form Helpers -->
<script src="http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/assets/js/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js"></script>
```

and here is the code for both the countries and states.

```
<div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-country="US" data-flags="true">
```

```
<div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-states" data-country="countries_states1" data-state=" ">
```

As I said, the countries work fine but the states do not populate anything and I need them to populate in relation to the country selected.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer online incase anyone else is looking. Delete the two divs above and add this:

```
<div id="countries_states2" class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-country="US" data-flags="true">
  <input type="hidden" value="">
  <a class="bfh-selectbox-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="bfh-selectbox" href="#">
    <span class="bfh-selectbox-option input-medium" data-option=""></span>
    <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <div class="bfh-selectbox-options">
  <div role="listbox">
    <ul role="option">
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-states" data-country="countries_states2">
  <input type="hidden" value="">
  <a class="bfh-selectbox-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="bfh-selectbox" href="#">
    <span class="bfh-selectbox-option input-medium" data-option=""></span>
    <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <div class="bfh-selectbox-options">
  <div role="listbox">
    <ul role="option">
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to keep the flag icon add data-flags="true" into the first div at the top

Comment: How get values for country and state ? onchange methods?